# Take limit of integral

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

How to solve this?
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^x (\arctan(x))^2 dx} {\sqrt{x^2+1}} $$
It looks like it is pretty hard to take this integral, so I assume that it's possible to do with fundamental theorem of calculus, but I just don't see how to interpret this limit as differentiation

Comment: Do you know L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: I think your integral is meant to read $\int_0^x\arctan^2tdt$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is $\frac {\infty}{\infty}$ form

So, using L'Hopital's we get $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{(\tan^{-1}x)^2}{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}} = \frac{\pi^2}{4} $

Comment: Thanks, but how can we prove that this integral is infinity?

Comment: @IvanIvan A simple approach: if $t>1$ then $\arctan(t)>\pi/4$ so $\int_0^x \arctan(t)^2 dt > \frac{\pi^2}{16} (x-1)$ for $x>0$. This is pretty much just an explicit calculation for the general result that if $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) dx$ exists and is nonzero then $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx$ diverges (to an infinity with whatever the sign of that limit was).

Comment: Either use by parts and solve the integral and it shows it diverges or better I liked Ian's approach

Comment: L'Hospital's rule does NOT require that the numerator approaches $0$.

Comment: @Mathsmerizing Yes on $0/0$.  NO on $\infty/\infty$.  In fact, if the denominator goes to $\infty$, the limit of the numerator doesn't even need to exist.

Comment: Agreed Mark. When we prove L'hopitals general case for g(x) $\to \infty$ we do not assume f(x) $\to \infty$

Comment: @Mathsmerizing From the end of the section [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Hôpital%27s_rule#General_proof).  "In case 2 the assumption that f(x) diverges to infinity was not used within the proof. This means that if |g(x)| diverges to infinity as x approaches c and both f and g satisfy the hypotheses of L'Hôpital's rule, then no additional assumption is needed about the limit of f(x): It could even be the case that the limit of f(x) does not exist."